# Install pip for Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, macos-sierra

When I type `python3 --version` in terminal it shows Python 3.6.0.

When I type in `pip --version` it shows

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

How do I get it from `Python/2.7` to `Python/3.6`?

Comment: What about `pip3 --version`?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: So, you have `pip` already installed.

Comment: I was basically watching a Django tutorial by Derek Banas and he said that it should show Python/3.x Version when I type in pip --version

Comment: So what is going on in here?

Comment: You just need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` for Python 3.6.0.

Comment: How do you know all this stuff? Can you point me to some documentation that I can read so that I can figure this stuff by myself? Thank you.

Comment: @HarshKhajuria Either change default python version to python3 or use virtualenv. Using virtualenv is recommended way to go.

Answer (score 10):

From Python 3.4 `pip` is baked into standard Python. You can use it like,

```
python3 -m pip install SomePackage
```

as mentioned in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#basic-usage).

Comment: This worked for me and I was able to install the `requests` package for `python3` by doing `python3 -m pip install requests` on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The guaranteed cross-platform way to run a module 'mod' with a particular python version 'pythonx' is

```
pythonx -m mod
```

On Windows, with the py launcher, I might run any of

```
py -2.7 -m pip
py -3.5 -m pip
py -3.6 -m pip
```

There is then no question which python and pip combination I will get.  Other systems with one 2.x and 3.x version installed can use

```
python2 -m pip
python3 -m pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 10.8+ come with Python 2.7 installed by default. This is why when you try to see what your pip version is, it comes back with 9.0.1 from Python 2.7. You shouldn't ever uninstall or move the system-installed Python because it's used internally by the Mac OS and other third-party developers, but a quick workaround is to just use `pip3` in place of `pip`.

A helpful resource on using Python 3 with Mac OS X can be found [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html).